# tikzpicture, too high tikzpicture produce a first empty page, how do I fix?

Tags: tikz-pgf

A trivial issue, but I am not able to fix it.

The following code should produce a single page output. Since the tikzpicture is too high, the output has a first empty page. How do I fix it?  (I get a single page output when I have a shorter string of B's)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{varwidth} % for Large braces
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
mynode/.style={fill,circle,inner sep=3pt,outer sep=0pt}
}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, arrows, decorations.markings, decorations.text, arrows.meta}

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{landscape}
    \hspace*{-3.3cm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append]
        \def\ra{13}
        \def\rii{-9}
        \coordinate (a) at (\rii,0);
        \coordinate (aa) at (\rii,5);
    \draw[black,thick, -latex] (a) -- (aa);  
    \draw[black,thick, -latex] 
    (a) -- (\ra,0) 
    node[pos=0.32,mynode,fill=blue,label={[label distance=0.2cm,text depth=2ex,rotate=75, align=left, font=\Large\linespread{0.8}\selectfont ]right: \textcolor{blue}{{\Large{\textbf{\today}:}}} \textcolor{blue}{{\Large{AAAAAAAAAA}}} \textcolor{blue}{{\Large{BBBBBB-BBB}}}  \\ \textcolor{blue}{{\Large{CCCCCCCCCC}}}  
}]{};  

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your diagram is higher than the available `\textheight` on the first page and TeX moves it to the next page (hoping there's more space).

Comment: I am lost, isn't  \textheight on the second page as high as on the first? Anyway, how do I force to fit ii into the first page?

Comment: It is, but the algorithm doesn't know that. It just knows (not enough space -> move to next page). If there's still not enough and there are no more pages, it outputs the float anyway rather than disregarding it. You should have warnings in your log file about this. Three options to get it on the first page: (1) make the picture smaller (2) make the space available larger (e.g. increase `\textheight`) or (3) lie. Pick your poison.

Comment: I fixed things by `\usepackage[a4paper,hmargin={1cm,0.7in}, vmargin={0.8cm,01.8in}]{geometry}`.Thanks for your help.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a more universal approach.

#### 1) Compile the Tikz drawing as a separate .pdf

Say, it's called `tikz.tex`, compiling as `tikz.pdf`; kindly recognize the different documentclass:

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    every node/.append,
    mynode/.style={fill,circle,inner sep=3pt,outer sep=0pt}
    ]
        \def\ra{13}
        \def\rii{-9}
        \coordinate (a) at (\rii,0);
        \coordinate (aa) at (\rii,5);
    \draw[black,thick, -latex] (a) -- (aa);  
    \draw[black,thick, -latex] 
    (a) -- (\ra,0) 
    node[pos=0.32,mynode,fill=blue,label={[label distance=0.2cm,text depth=2ex,rotate=75, align=left, font=\Large\linespread{0.8}\selectfont ]right: \textcolor{blue}{{\Large{\textbf{\today}:}}} \textcolor{blue}{{\Large{AAAAAAAAAA}}} \textcolor{blue}{{\Large{BBBBBB-BBB}}}  \\ \textcolor{blue}{{\Large{CCCCCCCCCC}}}  
}]{};  

 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: drawing]

#### 2) Include this .pdf in your main file

Boiled down to the relevant parts, just do, with setting scale or width as needed:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{varwidth} % for Large braces

% ~~~ not needed here ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
%\usepackage{tikz}
%\tikzset{
%mynode/.style={fill,circle,inner sep=3pt,outer sep=0pt}
%}
%
%\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,intersections}
%\usetikzlibrary{calc, arrows, decorations.markings, decorations.text, arrows.meta}

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{landscape}
    \hspace*{-3.3cm}
    \includegraphics[scale=1]{tikz}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]