# Prevent quantikz from altering tikz behaviour?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd, tikzlibrary, quantikz

This code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
% \usetikzlibrary{quantikz2}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
    A \arrow[rrrr, ""] \& \& \& \& B \arrow[rd, ""] \\
    \& \& \& \& \& C \\
    D \arrow[rrrr, ""] \& \& \& \& E \arrow[ru]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

produces this:

[image]

This code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz2}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
    A \arrow[rrrr, ""] \& \& \& \& B \arrow[rd, ""] \\
    \& \& \& \& \& C \\
    D \arrow[rrrr, ""] \& \& \& \& E \arrow[ru]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

produces this:

[image]

How do I get the first result if I need to use `quantikz` in my document? Loading `quantikz` locally for each diagram seems [painful](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111146/is-it-possible-to-load-a-tikz-library-locally).

Comment: I think you mean "altering" not "alternating" in the title. Also, `quantikz` not `quantikz2`.

Comment: It's `quantikz2` actually.

Comment: Not sure, what you are after. However, this approach lets you combine anything, because you avoid such conflicts, while preserving vector graphics: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/713595/245790.

Comment: `\usetikclibrary{quantikz2}` uses xparse and etoolbox to modify TikZ. making it incompatible with any other use of TikZ,  Tikzcd should't cause any problems.

Answer (score 1):

1. To have both, separate in space (i.e. in files here).
2. Join later.

#### 1) create and compile individual files

Kindly recognize the different documentclass.

t-tex:

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
    A \arrow[rrrr, ""] \& \& \& \& B \arrow[rd, ""] \\
    \& \& \& \& \& C \\
    D \arrow[rrrr, ""] \& \& \& \& E \arrow[ru]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

q.tex:

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz2}

\begin{document}
\begin{quantikz}[ampersand replacement=\&]
    A \arrow[rrrr, ""] \& \& \& \& B \arrow[rd, ""] \\
    \& \& \& \& \& C \\
    D \arrow[rrrr, ""] \& \& \& \& E \arrow[ru]
\end{quantikz}
\end{document}
```

#### 2) Your main document

main.tex:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{t}
 \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{q}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]